# How to design function in flow style in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

suppose I have a util object with two function

```
object t {

  def funA(input:String,x:Int):String = "hello"*x

  def funB(input:String,tail:String):String = input + ":" + tail

}
```

if i run

```
funB(funA("x",3),"tail")
```

I get the result = xxx:tail

the question is how to design these two function then I can call them in a flow style like:

"x" funA(3) funB("tail")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a case class with a `String` field (corresponding to the original functions first argument),

```
case class StringOps(s: String) {
  def funA(x:Int):String = s*x
  def funB(tail:String):String = s + ":" + tail
}
```

and an implicit for converting `String` to `StringOps`,

```
implicit def String2StringOps(s: String) = StringOps(s)
```

you can enable the following usage,

```
scala> "hello" funA 3
hellohellohello

scala> "hello" funA 3 funB "tail"
hellohellohello:tail
```

Answer (score 2):

Extend String, Using implicit class,

```
implicit class CustomString(str: String) {
    def funcA(count:Int) = str * count
    def funB(tail:String):String = str + ":" + tail
  }

  println("x".funcA(3).funB("tail"))
```